# awkwardness in creating object

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, new-operator

`Temp1 t1=new Temp2();`
Here Temp1 is superclass of Temp2. The code works perfectly fine and **t1** do acts as a reference variable for Temp1 but how can **Temp2()** works as constructor for Temp1?

Comment: You're confusing objects, variables, and references. (And type inheritance.)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: t1 in this case at runtime is of type Temp2, not Temp1

Answer (score 2):

This is the basis for [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29): Imagine you have several child classes that inherit from you parent class. You want to use all these child classes through the interface / methods defined on your parent class, without worrying about the implementation details in each child class (each might do something different, but with the same overall semantics).

This is possible because the child class has a [IS A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship with its parent class since child inherits from parent.

Answer (score 2):

```
T1 do act as reference variable for Temp1
```

No, actually t1 variable is **type of Temp1** which act as reference variable for **Temp2**.

```
but how can Temp2() works as constructor for Temp1
```

Inheritance is object oriented feature by which child class inherit all the property of parent class, in this case **temp2** is child class which inheriting all the methods from its superclass **temp1**. Therefore **temp2** is a type of **temp1** family and therefore **Temp2 constructor can refer by the Temp1 reference variable(t1)**.

You Must Read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
           https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 0):

> but how can Temp2() works as constructor for Temp1?

It doesn't. It is other way around. It is `Temp1 t1` which behaves as reference which can hold any kind of object form `Tempt1` *family*, and since `Temp2 extends Temp1` it is considered as type of `Type1`.

This is perfectly safe because `Type2` inherits all members of `Type1` so there is no risk that some method or field invoked on `t1` reference will try to execute/use some undefined method/variable.

Also thanks to polymorphism (or to be more precise [late-binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java) - searching and executing code of method at runtime based on instance type, not reference type) method of `Type2` will be invoked instead of `Type1`. This allows us to have abstract classes and interfaces.