# What is the difference between the Object's property?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I am so much confused for the following declaration of the object in Java. for ex: 
I need to create a object for the `ClassName`

I can do it in two ways:

1. `Object obj = new ClassName();`
2. `ClassName obj1 = new ClassName();`

what is the primary difference between this `obj` and `obj1` or they are the same?

Comment: The objects are instances of the same type, but the variables have a different compile-time type...

Comment: Read about dynamic polymorphysm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between dynamic and static polymorphism in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java)

Comment: Almost exact duplicate too: [awkwardness in creating object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31327896)

Answer (score 2):

Object is a superclass of ClassName, in fact, it's the top-most class of all classes you create. Java allows you to use a subclass as if it were an instance of a superclass (it has the same methods, although they might be overriden).

The difference lies in how you can use them. In the first case, the compiler will see obj as a reference of type Object and the reference actually points to an instance of type ClassName. In your second case, your compiler will see obj1 as a reference of type ClassName and the reference points to an instance of type ClassName.

In the first case, you won't be able to call any methods declared in the subclass, since the type Object doesn't actually contain these methods (and the compiler won't know about them), whereas you can use the second way to call methods and access fields declared in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

`Object obj = new ClassName();` your creating a reference `obj` of type `Object` and making it refer to a `ClassName` instance .

`ClassName obj1 = new ClassName();` , here both the object created and reference are of type `ClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading about the concept of *(dynamic) polymorphism* in the official Java tutorial by Oracle.

[Link is right here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)